# Can one detect a cyclic and separating vector for a concrete $C^*$-algebra using a dense subalgebra?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras

Let $A$ be a $C^*$ algebra of operators acting on some Hilbert space $H$, and $A_0$ is a norm dense $*$-subalgebra of $A$. Suppose there exists some unit vector $\xi \in H$, such that (i) $A_0 \xi$ is dense in $H$; (ii) $a\xi = 0$ if and only if $a=0$ for all $a \in A_0$, i.e. $\xi$ is separating for $A_0$.

**Question**: is $\xi$ also separating for $A$, i.e. is it true that $a \xi = 0$ implies $a=0$ for all $a \in A$?

It is clear that if the vector state $\omega_\xi$ of $\xi$ is a trace on $A$, then the answer is affirmative by (i). More generally, if $\omega_\xi$ is a KMS state (so that we have sufficient control of $\omega_\xi$ from being away from a trace using suitable automorphisms of $A$), then the answer is still affirmative. But in general, I don't know the answer, and suspect that there is a counter-example.

Comment: I recently answered a similar question on MSE: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4249114/a-ast-representation-of-a-c-algebra-on-a-hilbert-space-h-that-is-non/4249220#4249220 I'm not saying something similar will work here, but might offer a bit of insight.

Comment: @QuantumSpace Thanks for pointing out this "similar question". It seems to me at the moment that the question here is much more delicate as can be seen in the last paragraph. I think my question is closer in spirit with [this one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/93295/separating-vectors-for-c-algebras). Note that the "topological side" here seems more delicate than the "measure-theoretic side" presented there in the counter-example of Ozawa.

Comment: Yes, your question is definitely more difficult to answer. I share your belief that there should exist a counterexample.

Comment: Maybe I should mention that if we drop the requirement of $\xi$ being cyclic, then one can construct a  counter-example as follows: take the free group on two generators $F_2$, and let $A_f$ be its full $C^*$-algebra, $A_r$ the reduced one, $q : A_f \to A_r$ the canonical quotient, $\tau$ the canonical trace on $A_r$ given by the vector state determined by the Dirac at the identity, and $\tau_f = \tau \circ q$. Now consider the universal representation $(\pi, H)$ of $A_f$. We have $\tau_f$ is a vector state (every state of $A_f$ is since we are using the universal representation)...

Comment: ...yet the corresponding vector  is separating for the group ring $\mathbb{C}[F_2]$ which is dense in $A_f$, but not separating for $A_f$ since $q$ has nontrivial kernel.

Comment: Doesn't $\xi$ cyclic and separating for $A_0$ imply it's  cyclic and separating for the commutant $A_0'$, and then for its double commutant, which contains $A$?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_and_separating_vector) confirms my memory ...

Comment: @NikWeaver No, it doesn't. The problem lies in $\xi$ being separating for $A$ _does not imply_ it is cyclic for $A'$, even when $A$ is a $C^*$ algebra (though this is true if $A$ is von Neumann algebra). See the counter-example given by Ozawa [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/93295/separating-vectors-for-c-algebras) as mentioned in one of the comment above.

Comment: Just a casual remark that just because something is written in Wikipedia or other well-established literature does not mean it is correct. If you check the Wikipedia entry for the open mapping theorem, the incorrect version given by Rudin in his book is still cited there: just take any infinite dimensional Banach space $X$ equipped with norm topology mapping identically to itself equipped with the weak topology, the image is certainly not meager as it is the whole space, but the image is never metrizable, not to mention to be an $F$-space, and the mapping is never open either...

Comment: @RickSternbach I see, thank you.  Maybe that's why I couldn't remember the proof ...

Comment: @HuaWang Yes, having corrected a few Wikipedia entries myself I am aware that there are errors. BTW it is very easy to edit a Wikipedia page and I encourage you to correct the errors you run across.

Comment: @HuaWang In an infinite-dimensional Banach space, the unit ball is weakly closed and has empty interior, so the whole space is meagre in the weak topology. The whole space not being meagre is a nontrivial condition on a topological space, implied by but not equivalent to being a Baire space.

Comment: @RobertFurber You are right. I made a silly mistake and this does not constitute a counter-example for Rudin's version of open mapping theorem after all. I remember that I found the argument in Rudin not clear to me when proving the map is open without assuming the target space being metrizable, and mistakenly thought this seemingly naive example shows the necessity to add the condition of metrizability of the target space. Thanks for pointing this out, and I'll use this as a reminder for myself to be more cautious when using words like "certainly" or "obviously" etc.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's a counter-example. Take $A_0:=\mathbb{C}[F(s,t)]\subset A:=\mathrm{C}^*_{\mathrm{r}}(F(s,t))$, where $F(s,t)$ is the free group on $\{s,t\}$, $E\colon A\to \mathrm{C}^*_{\mathrm{r}}(F(s))$ the canonical conditional expectation, and $\psi\colon \mathrm{C}^*_{\mathrm{r}}(F(s)) \cong C(\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})\ni f\mapsto 2\int_0^{1/2} f(r)\,dr$.
Note that the conditional expectation $E$ is faithful and the state $\psi$ is faithful on the algebra $\mathbb{C}[F(s)]$ of trigonometric polynomials.
Put $\varphi=\psi\circ E$ and let $(\pi,H,\xi)$ denote the GNS-triplet.
Since $\varphi$ is faithful on $A_0$, the vector $\xi$ is separating on $\pi(A_0)$.
It is also cyclic because it is a GNS vector.
However $\xi$ is not separating for $\pi(A)$, since $\psi$ is supported on $[0,1/2]$ and $\pi$ is faithful.

Comment: I was trying to gain some "intuition" as to what makes this work.  I guess that $A$ is simple is a key ingredient...

Answer (score 2):

Here is another example, following a somewhat naive intuition that there could be a suitably chosen involutive algebra generated by operators with sufficiently large range, thus having a high chance of admitting a cyclic and separating vector, yet its norm closure contains sufficiently many rank-one projections, thus such a vector could not be separating for the closure.

Let $H=\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$ and $(\delta_k)$ the standard orthonormal basis. Denote the corresponding matrix unit by $e_{i,j}$, i.e. $e_{i,j}(\sum_k \xi_k \delta_k) = \xi_j \delta_i$ and pose $e_k = e_{k,k}$. Consider two self-adjoint operators $S, T \in B(H)$ defined as follows:

- $S(\delta_0) = \delta_0$, and $S(\delta_k) = \frac{1}{2k}\delta_k$ for $k\ne 0$; or equivalently, $S = e_{0} + \sum_{k \ne 0} \frac{1}{2k}e_k$ with resepct to the norm topology.
- $T(\delta_0) = 0$, and $T(\delta_k) = - \delta_{-k}$; or equivalently, $T = -\sum_{k \ne 0} e_{k,-k}$ with respect to the strong topology.

We calculate
$$ ST = - \sum_{k \ne 0} \frac{1}{2k} e_{k,-k}
= \sum_{k \ne 0} \frac{1}{2k} e_{-k,k} = -TS. $$

Also note that $T^2 = 1 - e_0$, while $Te_0 = e_0 T = 0$ and $S^k e_0 = e_0 S^k = e_0$ for all $k \ge 0$, with the usual convention that $S^0=1$.

Let $\mathcal{A}_0$ be the unital (involutive since $S$, $T$ are self-adjoint) subalgebra generated by $S$ and $T$, and let $\mathcal{A}$ be the norm closure of $\mathcal{A}_0$. By the above calculation, we see that $\mathcal{A}_0$ is linearly spanned by $e_0$, $S^i$ with $i \ge 0$ and $S^i T$ with $i \ge 0$.

Let $\xi = \delta_0 + \sum_{k > 0}\frac{1}{k}(\delta_k + (-1)^k \delta_{-k}) = (\xi_k) \in H$. We claim that $\xi$ is separating for $\mathcal{A}_0$. Indeed, let $x = a e_0 + \sum_{i=0}^N (b_i S^i + c_i S^i T) \in \mathcal{A}_0$, with $a$, $b_i$, $c_i$ being coefficients. To prove the claim, we only need to show that $x \xi = 0$ implies $x = 0$. We calculate
$$ x \xi = \left(a+ \sum_{i=0}^N b_i\right) \delta_0
+ \sum_{k \ne 0}\sum_{i=0}^N (2k)^{-i} (b_i  \xi_k -  c_i \xi_{-k}) \delta_k. $$
Suppose $x \xi = 0$. For $k > 0$, we compare the coefficients of $\delta_k$ in $x \xi$.  If $k$ is odd, we have $\xi_k = - \xi_{-k} \ne 0$ and $\sum_{i=0}^N (2k)^{-i}(b_i + c_i)=0$. Take any $N+1$ different odd $k$ and note that the corresponding Vandermonde determinant does not vanish, we get $b_i + c_i = 0$ for all $0 \le i \le N$. Similarly, if $k$ is even, then $\xi_k = \xi_{-k} \ne 0$, and $\sum_{i=0}^N (2k)^{-i}(b_i - c_i)=0$. This time, taking $N+1$ different even $k$ shows that $b_i - c_i = 0$ for all $0 \le i \le N$. Hence $b_i = c_i = 0$ for all $0 \le i \le N$. Comparing the coefficient of $\delta_0$ now gives $a=0$ too. Thus $x=0$, and $\xi$ is indeed separating for $\mathcal{A}_0$.

Since $\mathcal{A}_0$ is norm dense in $\mathcal{A}$, cyclicity of $\xi$ for $\mathcal{A}_0$ is equivalent to that for $\mathcal{A}$, which we now establish. By the definition of $S$, we have $\| S - e_0 \| = \frac{1}{2}$ and $e_0 (S - e_0) = (S - e_0) e_0 = 0$. Hence for all positive integer $n$, we have $e_0 + (S - e_0)^n = S^n \in \mathcal{A}_0$, which converges to $e_0$ in norm. Thus $e_0 \in \mathcal{A}$. Similarly, $(2(S - e_0))^{2n+1} \in \mathcal{A}_0$ converges in norm to $(e_1 - e_{-1}) \in \mathcal{A}$, and $(2(S - e_0))^{2n} \in \mathcal{A}_0$ converges in norm to $(e_1 + e_{-1}) \in \mathcal{A}$. Thus both $e_1$ and $e_{-1}$ are in $\mathcal{A}$. Continue in this way (i.e. raising $4(S - e_0 - \sum_{0 < |k| \le 1} \frac{1}{2k}e_k)$ to odd powers and even powers then taking limits), we get $e_2, e_{-2} \in \mathcal{A}$. Just repeat the procedure, by induction, we see that every $e_k \in \mathcal{A}$. Since $\xi_k \ne 0$, we have $\delta_k = \xi_k^{-1}e_k \xi \in \mathcal{A}\xi$ for all $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, so $\xi$ is cyclic for $\mathcal{A}$, hence for $\mathcal{A}_0$.

Finally, by definition, $-Te_{-1} \delta_{-1} = \delta_1$ so $0 \ne e_1 - Te_{-1} = e_1 + e_{1,-1} \in \mathcal{A}$, and
$$ (e_1 + e_{1,-1})\xi = (\xi_1 + \xi_{-1})\delta_1 = 0 $$
showing $\xi$ is not separating for $\mathcal{A}$. Normalizing $\xi$ to a unit vector answers the question.